# Android launch play store from an activity and then force play store to return back

Tags: android, google-play

From my activity i am launching play store and making users to install an app but i also want play store to return the user back to my activity.

CODE TO LAUNCH PLAY STORE

```
String blueFireId = "com.bluefirereader"; // this is out of the oncreate function

    try {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id="+blueFireId)));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+blueFireId)));
    }
```

The above code is working fine, also is there any way to make play store return the user back to my activity so that i can continue with the remaining steps required to use my app

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot control the behaviour of any other apps that are not your own.

Comment: gosh , ok i will do it the old plain way then , thanks for it